# Custom @font-face Tailwind - font isn't displaying

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a custom font to a React project that uses Tailwind.

I've added the font - tiempos-headline-medium.woff2 to /public and changed the following:

node_modules > tailwindcss > tailwind.css

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
    font-family: "tiempos-headline";
    src: local('tiempos-headline'), url("tiempos-headline-medium.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 600;
  }
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        brand: {
          'pink-link': '#FB335A',
          'pink': '#FB335A',
          300: '#000000',
          400: '#f8f8f8',
          500: '#000000',
          600: '#000000',
          700: '#000000',
        }
      },
      animation: {
        loading: 'rotate 1s linear infinite',
      }
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['aktiv-grotesk', 'sans-serif'],
      serif: ['tiempos-headline', 'serif'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But the font isn't showing - it's displaying just a serif - any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure that the path of the font is correct in your `font-face` directive in the **css** file.

With a file structure like:

```
root_project
  | tailwind.config.js
  | node_modules
  | src
  | public
  | __ images
  | __ tiempos-headline-medium.woff2
  ...
```

Write your css path with an absolute path : `url("/tiempos-headline-medium.woff2")`

2. In `tailwind.config.js` file, move the directive `fontFamily: {}` into the `extend: {}` object to add a font and **extend** the font config.

If you want to **override** completely the default font, move the directive `fontFamily: {}` into the `theme: {}` object.

---

Config example based on your setup:

- style.css

```css
/* as the .woff2 file is in the public dir, we use absolute path "/" */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tiemposHeadline';
  src: url('/tiempos-headline-medium.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

- tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: { // we name our custom font "tiempos"
        tiempos: ['tiemposHeadline', 'serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

- in a component:

```html
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <h1 className="font-tiempos">Custom Font</h1>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you - can I check this is the correct format for tailwind.config.js as it isn't working - 

https://jsfiddle.net/dh741ztg/

Comment: @gilessmith I edited the answer with config examples, if you can't get it working, please give us a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project.

Answer (score 0):

firstly include it my index.html file as a link you can see poppins

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Bhrugu Tundeliya</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

so this is how I am doing it with tailwind

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './index.html',
        './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './src/**.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                'react-color': '#61DBFB',
            },
            backgroundImage: {
                Icsun: "url('./src/asset/sunny.png')",
                Icmoon: "url('./src/asset/half-moon.png')",
            },
            fontFamily: {
                poppins: ['poppins', 'sans-serif'],
            },
            animation: {
                '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
                '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

and in the common text component that I use everywhere

```
export const Text = ({
    children,
    className,
    onMouseLeave,
    onMouseDown,
    onMouseEnter,
    onMouseUp,
}: TextProps) => {
    return (
        <label
            onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
            onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
            onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
            onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
            className={`font-poppins ${className}`}
        >
            {children}
        </label>
    )
}
```

and it workes just fine.. you can spicy in the body in CSS also. I like to control all text so I make a component always.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a CDN version of the font so I can't use this method